# Check if the data not exist in php mysql active record then select to default code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

this code get me the data

```
function get_mdr_master($kode) {
        //$this->db->cache_on();
        $this->db->select('mdr_debit, mdr_debit_npg, mdr_debit_pl');
        $this->db->where('kode',$kode);
        $query = $this->db->get('mapping_mcc_mdr');
        //echo $query;die;
        return $query->result();
    }
```

but if the data ($kode) is not exist i'd like to point `$this->db->where('kode',$kode);`to select $kode with value 0000 that i already prepare in the database.

so how to make the if else statement that if the data is not exist in database it will select 0000 as the default $kode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if where with `$kode` has more than 0 rows, if not, then do the same logic but with where `0000`:

```
function get_mdr_master($kode) {
    $this->db->select('mdr_debit, mdr_debit_npg, mdr_debit_pl');
    $this->db->where('kode', $kode);
    $query = $this->db->get('mapping_mcc_mdr');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        $this->db->select('mdr_debit, mdr_debit_npg, mdr_debit_pl');
        $this->db->where('kode', '0000');
        $query = $this->db->get('mapping_mcc_mdr');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Or (prettier):

```
function get_mdr_master($kode) {
    $this->db->where('kode', $kode);
    if ($this->db->count_all_results('mapping_mcc_mdr') < 1) {
        $kode = '0000'; // override $kode
    }
    $this->db->select('mdr_debit, mdr_debit_npg, mdr_debit_pl');
    $this->db->where('kode', $kode);
    $query = $this->db->get('mapping_mcc_mdr');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: np bro ;) updated method will probably be *slightly* faster